# Help with themeing the Admin Theme

Tags: 7, theming

I'm working on a D7 site at the moment and need a bit of help with the admin themes.

I've got 2 levels of admin for the site. Super user and a lower level admin that can only edit content they created. The lower level does not have access to the administration theme so their pages and admin forms are showing up in the site's content.

My question is: Is there a way of theming these pages through a template? Does it just use the basic node.tpl.php file? I can style the page in the CSS but I don't think this is going to be enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Admin pages are not nodes, so you would need to use the page template rather than the node template. You can copy your theme's page.tpl.php file and rename it to page--admin.tpl.php to create a template just for all admin pages.  If you need these changes to extend for node edit pages, then you would need to also create a page--node--edit.tpl.php file.

Another option is the [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module; it allows you to specify which theme to display based on path (i.e. you could change it for all admin/* paths) and/or based on user role (change theme for super users and low-level admins). You could choose a contributed admin theme to display on these conditions, or create a sub-theme of your front-end theme to display.

Comment: The admin page file seems to work fine. Ta.

Comment: It is not reflect on users page. any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar thing and the thing i did was that

You can let them access the Overlay (Access the administrative overlay
View administrative pages in the overlay.)

and then let them use the Use the administration toolbar

and then everything that you like to use let say "Access the content overview page" 
we will be placed in the toolbar and will be displayed in the overlay.

So the pages will not load right in the template but in the overlay so will be more clarify (but still uses the default template) but it's better

That solution came up to me..!

Comment: I always disable the overlay (for speeds sake) and the visuals for the site need the form to appear in the pages content.

Comment: Ok then go to the Configuration -> performance and enable Compress cached pages.
 Aggregate and compress CSS files.
 Aggregate JavaScript files. then enable to the role to access at toolbar administrator and then enable let say the "Access the content overview page" and disable the overlay and see how it shows also dont forget after all this clear cache. then you see this. http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/3792/showstack.png